# Jinja 2 - Django Form : rendering encodes HTML

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I was testing Jinja2 in a Django project and have a strange output.
When I render the form, some characters are HTML encoded (`&lt; &gt;` etc.)

In the template :

```
{{ form.as_p() }}
```

It renders to the browser :

```
<p><label for="id_username">Utilisateur:</label> <input autocomplete="off" id="id_username" type="text" name="username" maxlength="100" /></p> <p><label for="id_password">Mot de passe:</label> <input autocomplete="off" type="password" name="password" id="id_password" /></p>
```

Looking at sources :

```
&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;&amp;lt;label for=&amp;quot;id_username&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Utilisateur:&amp;lt;/label&amp;gt; &amp;lt;input autocomplete=&amp;quot;off&amp;quot; id=&amp;quot;id_username&amp;quot; type=&amp;quot;text&amp;quot; name=&amp;quot;username&amp;quot; maxlength=&amp;quot;100&amp;quot; /&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;
&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;&amp;lt;label for=&amp;quot;id_password&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Mot de passe:&amp;lt;/label&amp;gt; &amp;lt;input autocomplete=&amp;quot;off&amp;quot; type=&amp;quot;password&amp;quot; name=&amp;quot;password&amp;quot; id=&amp;quot;id_password&amp;quot; /&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;
```

Does anyone know this problem ?

Answer (score 27):

Jinja2 tries to be safe by [HTML-escaping the data](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#html-escaping). So you have to use `|safe` [filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#builtin-filters).

Though I haven't used Django with Jinja2, I believe this should work:

```
{{ form.as_p()|safe }}
```